# Como Carregar uma Activity usando a ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, xml

Código Da ProgressBar em  XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
    android:layout_height="11px"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:id="@+id/load"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52px"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Código da ProgressBar em Java

```
package game.app;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public  class LoadActivity extends  Activity {

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loadlayout);
  }
}
```

Activity que a ProgressBar vai carregar

```
package game.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

  private Button btiniciar;

  @Override

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menulayout);

    btiniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btiniciar);
    btiniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v) {

        @Override

        Intent it = new Intent(MenuActivity.this,LoadActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);
        finish();
      }
    });

    Button btconfig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btconfig);
    btconfig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View argO) {


      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Para mim não ficou claro o que você quer fazer. Só colou os códigos aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ProgressBar é um elemento da interface do usuário que indica o progresso de uma operação, nessa ação que você esta fazendo não há nenhuma ação que precise de ProgressBar.

Um exemplo onde pode se usar o ProgressBar é uso de AsyncTasks para carregamento de dados de API, download de imagem e etc... a não ser que para simular o progress você use algum postDelayed determinando um tempo para simular um delay na transição de tela.

```
 btiniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btiniciar);
    btiniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v) {

                //MOSTRAR PROGRESS
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                     //ESCONDER PROGRESS
                       Intent it = new Intent(MenuActivity.this,LoadActivity.class);
                       startActivity(it);
                       finish();
                    }
                }, 2000);
      }
    });
```